# Does it matter how long you spend docked in a damaged station?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

While performing rescue operations at a damaged station, do you continue to build up heat while docked? Flight control automatically brings you below deck and usually says something about "stabilizing core temperature", but does this actually happen? Or will I continue to build up heat as I navigate the Passenger Lounge?

Comment: Some testing so far is indicating that I am actually safe, and will consistently launch around 140%, but I'll need to do some more testing it's hard to tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I've seen, you don't take heat damage while docked.   You might need to pop a heat sink as soon as you lift off though.